# Return all Elements and Sub-elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Is it possible to use one LINQ query to return the values of all elements and child elements at one time? Using the query below I'm able to retrieve the first element, but not the child elements.

```
var query = from c in xDoc.Descendants("file")
            orderby c.Name
            select new
            {
                // This gets the main elements
                Name = (string)c.Element("name").Value,
            };
```

The XML File looks like this:

```
<files>
    <file id="1">
        <name>A file</name>
        <processDetails>
            <purpose>It's supposed to get files.</purpose>
            <filestoProcess>
                <file>alongfile.pgp</file>
                <file>Anotherfile.pgp</file>
                <file>YetAnotherfile.CSV</file>
            </filestoProcess>
            <schedule>
                <day>Mon</day>
                <day>Tue</day>
                <time>9:00am</time>
            </schedule>
            <history>
                <historyevent>Eh?</historyevent>
                <historyevent>Two</historyevent>
            </history>
        </processDetails>
    </file>
<files>
```

Also, once retrieved how would I access the child elements to populate a listbox and/or textbox?

Comment: Your sample XML doesn't contain any `<script>` elements. It's hard to help you when the code doesn't match the sample data. Likewise, you talk about multiple `name` elements, but you've only shown one... and it's not clear what you want the result to be, either. (Why are you using an anonymous type when you've only got one property, by the way?)

Comment: Assuming that script==file you still need to indicate which sub-elements you need in what form.

Comment: your closing `<files>` tag doesn't have a `/` in it

Comment: You need to give an example of the output desired.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your query is that your first `file` element seems to be a different type from your child `file` elements.

Because of this, when you actually execute your query, you'll fail to find the `name` attribute of the child `file` elements, and you'll get a `null reference exception when you try to invoke the`Value`property of the child`file` elements.

---

What you seem to be trying to do doesn't make very much sense.  but maybe you want something like the following:

```
var query = from c in xdoc.Descendants("file")
            orderby c.Name
            select new
            {
                // This gets the main elements
                Name = c.Element("name") == null ? c.Value : c.Element("name").Value,
            };
```